# get queuename on activemq server to push message

Tags: activemq-classic

I have got 10 queues on activemq server. 
I have producer which want to push messages on one of the queue (the producer will select the queue randomly run time to put message on queue), how can I pass destination name in createProducer method.
I understand that I need to pass an object of type Destination. the producer would know the queues name on the server. Is it possible to pass (or convert) a string to Destination object type and pass that to  createproducer method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly;

If you're running Java and have a valid session, you could use [Session.createQueue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/Session.html#createQueue(java.lang.String));

```
// Create a Destination using the queue name
Destination destination = session.createQueue("queue name");

// Create a MessageProducer from the Session to the Queue
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
```

[Here is a complete example of doing this at the Apache site](http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html).

Comment: Thanks for you reply Joachim, I knew this way of doing this however do I still need to createQueue if i already have a physical queue on the server? (I already created physical queues on server with some other program (class say)). If I already have queue on server and I know the name then cant I say something like "session.createProducer(<<queuename as String type>>). is there a way to convert say String to Destination and hence I dont need to call createQueue again for the same queue which is already there on server. (I know createQueue does not create queue again if its already there)

Comment: @Manglesh `createQueue` is a somewhat confusing name since it does not actually create the queue. From the docs; `Creates a queue identity given a Queue name. ... _Note that this method is not for creating the physical queue._ The physical creation of queues is an administrative task and is not to be initiated by the JMS API.` But then again, I may not understand your question correctly...?

Comment: I have 3 parts (classes) of my application, first producer, second to create physical queues on server, third consumer. I already have created queues in second part. Now I have physical queues on server which i want producer/consumer to use to push and receive messages. In second part, while creating queues, I created them physically by having junk message sent by producer and discarded by receiver. the reason for creating queues run time because I would come to know number of queues to create at runtime. so I am using this method instead of creating queues upfront by defining in xml

Comment: You must call createQueue in all your classes if you only have the queue names as Strings.  You can view the createQueue method as a factory for Queue objects and not a method to create the Queue on the JMS broker.  Not sure why that one method call gives you such heartburn.